# Grammar, concerning any exceptions of "wish" sentences

Tags: grammar

Which is correct "Do you ever wish (that) you had gone to..?" or "Do you ever wish (that) you went to..?"

Comment: Either one is grammatically correct. Whether it is correct *in your context* depends on the specific context.

Comment: The  specific context is taken from a "Sentence transformation" exercise and is as follows: "Do you ever regret not going to university?"-"Do you ever wish.............?"

Comment: So...you're asking homework questions?

Comment: Exam questions, to be more exact.

Comment: Great. Recommended reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: You might want to review how "wish" works: a matrix clause headed by "wish" that has a declarative content clause usually requires a modal preterite in that content clause. That means that if past time is to be indicated in that content clause, then usually some additional, er, stuff has to be used for that purpose. This is a difference between "wish" and "regret" as the head of a matrix clause.

Comment: They are both correct and mean roughly the same thing.

Comment: Hi @EvgeniyRandev Please note that a good question will explain what you have done to try to find the answer, and what exactly you are still confused about. You might also like to visit the English Language Learners site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct.

I wish I had gone to... seems to imply that you no longer go to... but you did once.

I wish I went to... seems to imply that you wish you went to... now, instead of where you do go.

Not 100% sure, but I think this is past vs perfect past tense.

**EDIT:**

To understand what I'm saying, try replacing "went to" and "gone to" with attended.  They both work.  However, the "Had" before "gone to" implies something that is no longer the case.  I had a beer, but I drank it.

It's the difference between "I wish I attended school" and "I wish I had attended school".

Consider these:

- "Do you ever wish you WENT TO (attended) Harvard instead?" - How I would phrase
  the question to a current Yale Student (Someone who goes to Yale).
- "Do you ever wish you HAD GONE TO (had attended) Harvard instead." - How I would
  phrase it to a Yale Graduate. (Someone who had gone to Yale, but doesn't).
- "I attend Yale, but I wish I WENT to Harvard." - How a current Yale
  student might say it.
- I graduated Yale, but I wish I HAD GONE to Harvard instead. - How a
  Yale Graduate Might say it.

Now try these:

- "I graduated Yale, but I wish I went to (attended) Harvard." - Sounds weird.  You wish you went to Harvard now?  Or then?  Are you looking for a second education?
- " I attend Yale, but I wish I had gone to (had attended) Harvard."  - You wish you had attended Harvard when?  Before
  going to Yale?

Yes, they are (sometimes) interchangeable, but the meanings do change subtly.

(Also, no offense to Yale graduates - they were just the first two that came to mind. =o)

Comment: "I wish I had gone to that party on Saturday" implies that I no longer go to the party, but I once did?  I fail to see how you came to this interpretation.

Comment: Yes, @Doc; 'I wish I had gone to' means you missed the opportunity. And though you may get another one, that one has gone forever.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You missed the opportunity yes, but that's my point.  Eli suggest that the meaning is that by saying "I wish I had gone to", you suggest that you DID go to the party, but no longer go to it.  Whereas "I wish I went to" suggests that you did NOT go to the party, and you wish you were there now instead of where you currently are.  I disagree with both interpretations.

Comment: @Doc I was spelling out the correction you rightly said this answer needs.

Comment: @Doc - I wish I had gone to that school, rather than the one I did.  I wish I went to that school.

Comment: @Eli that sentence doesn't clarify anything.  "I wish I had gone to that school, rather than the one I did." does not imply that you once went to 'that school'.  "I wish I went to that school." does not imply that you want to be there NOW instead of where you currently are.  They both imply that, now that you no longer go to any (related) school, you regret the choice or loss of opportunity.

Comment: I think what you meant to say was _but you could have_, rather than _but you did_.

Comment: +1 for your answer is basically right. "Wish" chews up (requires) a modal preterite in the subordinate clause to indicate modal remoteness; and so, "went to" is probably placing its situation in the present time (kinda) -- while "had gone to" is placing its situation in the past time (or else is using backshifting) as the past-tense of "had" is used for the modal remoteness requirement and the perfect construction can be used for the past time sphere or backshifting.